# Insufficient free space lvresize swap

Tags: lvm, swap

My task is resize swap partition which is of LVM type.
I turned off swap with `swapoff`. Now when I tried resize it
`sudo lvresize -L+1G /dev/ol/swap` it trigger error message
`Inssuficient free space 265 extends needed but only 0 available`.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the output of `pvs`?

Comment: Result from command `vgs` will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You do not have free space in this volume group. As you can read from the message:

> Inssuficient free space **265 extends needed** but only **0 available**